# “My cat always hits me” or “my cat only hits me”

Tags: sentence-meaning

“My cat always hits me,” “my cat only hits me.”

What is the semantic difference ?

Is “my cat always only hits me” valid one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cats don't normally "hit" people, they are said to *swipe*, *bite*,  *hiss* or *scratch* people.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A My cat punched me. OTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My cat always hits me." says something about the *frequency* of the event. He hits you often, or every time you meet him.

"My cat only hits me." can mean two different things, and in speech this would be determined by emphasis:

1. Your cat hits you and does nothing else to you. "My cat only *hits* me."
2. Your cat hits you but nobody else. "My cat only hits *me*." This is technically a *misplaced modifier*, but common in informal speech. The correct form is "My cat hits only me."

Both together says something about the nature of the cat's response and the consistency/frequency of it: "My cat always only hits me." is saying "Every time I try to pet my cat, he hits me and doesn't show any affection."

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? Can I say “my cat always hits me” if he hits me every time I shower him.

Comment: "I try and bathe my cat weekly, but he always hits me." would be an example of that sort of use, yes.